# set up right click menu to relock bitlocker drive

Tags: windows-8, right-click

I'm using window 8, i have a drive with bitlocker feature. After i unlock a drive, there are no ways in GUI to lock it again easily except using command

```
manage-bde -lock drive:
```

I want to have a right click menu of the drive that a item let me right click to run the above command to lock relative drive again.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21325-lock-drive-add-context-menu-bitlocker-drives.html

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? If you're concerned about someone accessing the drive while you're at lunch, lock your workstation instead Windows + L

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a process provided at eightforums.com.

www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21325-lock-drive-add-context-menu-bitlocker-drives.html

This will allow you to add a context menu that gives you the ability to lock an unlocked bitlocker encrypted external hard drive.

The code that the solution above uses passes the following instruction to the OS.

manage-bde.exe -lock -forcedismount

Comment: Please include *all* necessary information in your answer in case the link breaks.

Comment: I was concerned about the .vbs file hosted on the website being copyrighted. It doesn't explicitly state that it is, but I'm also not in favor of making that distinction either. I provided what I believe is as much as I reasonably can and provided the source. I understand the desire to have ALL of the information here, but then again what happens if the link for this thread breaks? Same concept. If what I provided isn't helpful I am willing to remove my answer.